# Android reading Mifare classic card

Tags: android, xamarin.android, nfc

I'm trying to read a mifare card. I can read the Tag object but I can't read the NdefMessages ... When I call the intent to retrieve the ndefMessages it returns a null value instead of an array. However I can read the ID and the techlist and when I read it with another app I can see the contents so the card has data.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Nfc;
using Android.Nfc.Tech;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NfcDemo.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "NfcDemo", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop | LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        private NfcAdapter _nfcAdapter;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());

            _nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this);
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            if (_nfcAdapter == null)
            {
                var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).Create();
                alert.SetMessage("NFC is not supported on this device.");
                alert.SetTitle("NFC Unavailable");
                alert.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                var ndefDiscover = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered);
                var techDiscover = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionTechDiscovered);
                var tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered);

                var filters = new[] { tagDetected, techDiscover, ndefDiscover };

                var intent = new Intent(this, this.GetType()).AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
                var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                _nfcAdapter.EnableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, null);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            _nfcAdapter.DisableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-", "");
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            if (intent.Action == NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered)
            {
                var tag = intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;
                if (tag != null)
                {
                    var techs = tag.GetTechList();
                    var id = tag.GetId();
                    var hexstring = ByteArrayToString(tag.GetId());

                    var rawMessages = intent.GetParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraNdefMessages);

                    if (rawMessages != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var message in rawMessages.Cast<NdefMessage>())
                        {
                            foreach (var record in message.GetRecords())
                            {
                                var typeBytes = record.GetTypeInfo();
                                var payloadBytes = record.GetPayload();
                                var type = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(typeBytes);
                                var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payloadBytes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking for `NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` not `NfcAdapter.ActionTagDiscovered` in you `onNewIntent`

but as you have not correctly asked to be sent NDEF messages in your intent filter, you won't get any, you should add `ndefDiscover.addDataType("*/*");` to tell it what type of NDEF messages your want before you pass the filter to `EnableForegroundDispatch`

Note "*/*" is to send all types, having no data type defined is to send zero data types.

Because TagDiscovered is a lower type than NDEF, even if you card has NDEF messages on it the background service won't parse them to put them in the Extras field as it is not expecting you to use them.

Docs on this are at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#foreground-dispatch

Comment: Hi Andrew thank you for the information! It doesn't find the ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, do you know why? Instead the action is one of ActionTagDiscovered

Comment: There are a number of reason why it won't ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, the main one I covered in my answer is that you had not added a DataType to your NDEF filter. The others are the card is NDEF capable but is not NDEF formatted, the card is NDEF formatted but there is no NDEF messages or the card is not NDEF capable.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks again for explaining, I downloaded the app TagInfo from NXP and in the tag description there is an field NdefFormatable and there is data on the card. Does this proves that the card is NDEF capable?

Answer (score 0):

Mifare Classic not work with NDEF, try somethink like this:

```
using Android.Nfc;
using Android.Nfc.Tech;

protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);

    Tag tag = intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag) as Tag;

    if (tag == null) return;
    
    MifareClassic card = MifareClassic.Get(tag);
    card.Connect();
    //read block 1 of sector 0
    if (card.AuthenticateSectorWithKeyA(0, new byte[] {0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff})) //replace if you have other auth keys
    {
        byte[] data = card.ReadBlock(1);
    }
    card.Close(); 
}
```